# How old were Avraham and Sarah when they got married?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, marriage, age, abraham, sarah

How old were Avraham Avinu and Sarah Imeinu when they got married?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From this [Yalkut Shimoni (16:78)](http://www.tsel.org/torah/yalkutsh/lechlecha.html), it seems like 25/15 as they were "barren from Yitzchak for 75 years".

Comment: That is also the age that the Sefer HaDoros says they were. However I saw in HaRav Avigdor Miller Zatzal's Sefer on Breishis that they were 18/8.

Comment: Was he the rav in Pittsburgh?  :-)

Comment: No, that's R' Yisroel Miller (yibadel lechayim tovim). R' Avigdor was in Brooklyn.

Comment: I do not think so

Comment: @Gershon: I don't have R' Avigdor's sefer at hand, but I seem to recall him saying something like "if Avram married Sarai at 18..." - in other words, that it's just his assumption, presumably based on בן שמונה עשרה לחופה.

Comment: It was a joke. You said 18/8 -- like stainless steel. So I suggested that he'd written that because he's from Pittsburgh (steel capital).

Answer (score 12):

Seder Hadoros also brings down two other opinions 1. from Sefer "Zekukin DeNorah" that Avrohom was 76 (making Sarah 66). He lso brings a Yeish Omrim that Avrohom was 50 at the time he married Sarh and Sarh was childless for 50 years.

Comment: Eli, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing in this excellent source! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking "register," above.

Answer (score 11):

Sefer Hayashar [says](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40009&pgnum=35) that Haran was 42 when Sarai was born to him. Further on, it [says](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40009&pgnum=49) that Haran died at age 82 (from being thrown into the fire with Avram), and that "at that time" Avram and Sarai married. So that would make them respectively 50 and 40.

Comment: That means when Pharaoh wants Sarah as his wife, Sarah is just married or not married yet?