# Yocheved giving birth so late

Tags: miracle, parshanut-torah-comment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(Neis) Miracle of Sarah giving birth at 90](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/neis-miracle-of-sarah-giving-birth-at-90)

I think the RambaN ask the question that if Yocheved was born when Yaakov came down,
then why doesn't the Torah mention the miraculous births of Miriam, Aharan and Moshe after Yocheved was 120 years old.

Does anyone offer an answer?

Comment: I just posted another answer there, take a look.