# How come the Torah doesn't recount how Avraham and Sarah met?

Tags: abraham, parashat-lech-lecha, sarah

We know how Yitzchak met Rivka, and how Yaakov met Rachel & Leah- but why doesn't the Torah tell us how Avraham and Sarah met?

If you want to say that it's because they weren't Jewish at the time they met- neither were Adam & Chava. Isn't the meeting of first Jewish couple incredibly significant?

Comment: She was his half-sister or niece. They probably knew each other their whole lives

Comment: Related, including some _midrashim_ that fill in some biographical details. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3212/3

Comment: @JoelK [arguably](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73964/759)

Comment: Supplemnting @JoelK's idea, regarding Yitzhak and Ya'akov, I think the Torah wanted to point out specifically the origins of the 12 tribes in detail including the methods of marriage for Yitzchak and Ya'akov. I..e, G-d promises Avraham that his descendants will be as numerous as the stars. So, the Torah provides details as to how this happens. That promise didn't occur prior to Avraham being married.